# Is this smallest equivalent relation right?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Lets say $R={(1,3),(2,2),(1,4)}⊆\underline{4}×\underline{4}$ is a relation to $\underline{4}$. I'm looking for the smallest equivalent relation to $\underline{4}$.

My idea was the following:
It has to be reflexive, so we need $(1,1),(3,3),(4,4)$

It has to be transitive: We don’t need more relations

It has to be symmetric: We need $(3,1),(4,1)$

Now I wanted to ask you, if this is right, because I think, now I could create a relation $(4,1)∧(1,3)$ which doesn’t imply $(4,3)$, which would be contradict to transitive. Does this mean that I also have to add the relation (4,3) or is it an equivalent relation without? Do I have to go over the 3 steps over and over again, until there is nothing more, I miss out like the relation $(4,3)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add $(4,3)$ and $(3,4)$ and you are done.

Notice that $2$ is only related to itself.

If you draw out the graph with $4$ nodes and introduce an arc if they are related, you will see a complete graph of $3$ nodes and another complete graph of a single node (that would be node $2$).

Comment: Okay, but this also means, that I have to go over all of my relations over and over again, until there is nothing more to add to make sure they meet the equivalent requirements?

Comment: yes, you have to check that you do not left things out.

Comment: okay, perfect. Thank you very much!